# Where can I find a web widget that combines a bar chart and selector?

Tags: html, jquery, user-interface

I'm looking for a UI element that combines bar charts with selectors as seen in [Google's stock screener](https://www.google.com/finance#stockscreener). A jQuery plugin would be ideal, but I would settle for anything similar.

Comment: What do you think about high charts? You need a bit of coding for the selectors, but the API is provided for the same

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Range Navigator](http://jsfiddle.net/jr8x19vz/) allows for creating bar charts with selectors. There is a free [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) available.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.